# 21.10 - AX200 wifi randomly drops, switching to CONNECTED_SITE

Tags: networking, network-manager

I recently upgraded from 21.04 to 21.10 and my wifi (which used to work perfectly) now randomly drops until I cycle the networking off / on again from the menubar icon.

I was recently able to observe the precise moment when this happened.

`sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager` identified the following event:

```
Nov 01 23:23:44 ganymede NetworkManager[3858]: <info>  [1635834224.1478] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
```

Meanwhile, the relevant section of `/var/log/syslog` is:

```
Nov  1 23:23:44 ganymede NetworkManager[3858]: <info>  [1635834224.1478] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Nov  1 23:23:44 ganymede dbus-daemon[3853]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.11' (uid=0 pid=3858 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManage
r --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Nov  1 23:23:44 ganymede systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Nov  1 23:23:44 ganymede dbus-daemon[3853]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Nov  1 23:23:44 ganymede systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Nov  1 23:23:54 ganymede systemd[1]: NetworkManager-dispatcher.service: Deactivated successfully.
```

Finally, hunting through `dmesg -T | less` turns up the following, from right before the event in question:

```
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Status: 0x00000040, count: 6
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 63.c04f3485.0 cc-a0-63.ucode
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000071 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UMAC_FATAL    
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0000A200 | trm_hw_status0
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x004FAA7E | branchlink2
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x004F163E | interruptlink1
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x004F163E | interruptlink2
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0000AE8C | data1
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00001000 | data2
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x9BC15FE3 | beacon time
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x1A5F92BA | tsf low
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0000004E | tsf hi
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x1C1AFB9A | time gp2
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0000003F | uCode version major
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0xC04F3485 | uCode version minor
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000340 | hw version
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00C89000 | board version
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x80E0FC03 | hcmd
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x24020000 | isr0
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00400000 | isr1
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x08F00002 | isr2
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00C37FCC | isr3
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x05D9001C | last cmd Id
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0000AE8C | wait_event
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x000000D4 | l2p_control
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00018034 | l2p_duration
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000007 | l2p_mhvalid
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000081 | l2p_addr_match
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000009 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x000048F0 | flow_handler
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Status: 0x00000040, count: 7
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x20003463 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x8045541A | umac branchlink2
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0xC0084260 | umac interruptlink1
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x1A5F92AE | umac data1
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x1C1AFB8D | umac data2
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x5AF15252 | umac data3
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0000003F | umac major
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0xC04F3485 | umac minor
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x1C1AFB95 | frame pointer
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0xC0885E0C | stack pointer
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0061010C | last host cmd
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: IML/ROM dump:
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000003 | IML/ROM error/state
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00005977 | IML/ROM data1
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000080 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x80290021 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00050008 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0000A503 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x80000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00100530 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000532 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00100530 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000532 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 4 fired (delay=0ms).
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:37 2021] ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:38 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Got NSS = 4 - trimming to 2
[Mon Nov  1 23:22:38 2021] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Got NSS = 4 - trimming to 2
```

Anyone have any ideas?

P.S. - almost forgot my `sudo lshw -class network`

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 1a
       serial: dc:41:a9:e2:13:64
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.13.0-20-generic firmware=63.c04f3485.0 cc-a0-63.ucode ip=192.168.4.62 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:133 memory:fc700000-fc703fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I211 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: enp5s0
       version: 03
       serial: 18:c0:4d:82:07:21
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.13.0-20-generic firmware=0. 6-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:24 memory:fc600000-fc61ffff ioport:f000(size=32) memory:fc620000-fc623fff
```

[edit #1] - For what it's worth, I've now captured another one of these events, with a seemingly identical "Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0." in dmesg, followed by a statechange "NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE" in journalctl, so this does seem to be the causal chain.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing, with a slightly different firmware version on the 4th line of your dmesg. `59.601f3a66.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-59.ucode` for my AX201

Comment: @spazm - Can I ask if you have a home wifi network with the 5ghz and 2.4ghz channels with the same SSID?

I found this [thread over](https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/ris5ep/wifi_droppingslow_after_2110_update/) on the pop_os subreddit which seems to be discussing the same phenomenon.

In my case, I _do_ have 5ghz and 2.4ghz wifi networks with the same SSID.

I also apparently have spotty signal where the affected computer is, so now I'm wondering if the problem is triggered by the computer trying to switch connections.

Comment: Yes.  My eero wifi uses the same name for 2.4 and 5 ghz connections.  I also had a similar name between primary and guest networks. disabling guest network did not change behavior.

Comment: Hah! I'm also on eero wifi. When I checked, there didn't seem to be an easy way to split the networks into different SSIDs... let me know if you find one. I'd prefer not to have to buy different networking hw.

Comment: EERO definitely does NOT have a way to split / rename the networks, and don't plan to add.  Can be a pain for 2.4 only IoT devices.  You can disable the 5G for 10 minutes for testing under settings ->Troubleshooting -> my device won't connect -> device is 2.4Gz only -> Temp pause 5 Ghz. (pauses for 10 minutes)

Comment: Added an additional AP for testing, 20 minutes in I am still connected to 5Ghz. Next I'm enabling the 2.4Ghz and using the same SSID.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Will be interested to hear how it goes!

Comment: I thought my eero experience improved a little when I enabled band steering, but only extended the time between crashes.  Wifi works perfectly connected to a tp-link AP. Trying a backported intel driver next.